# I can't get any mail from Django send_mail? Where is my mistake?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to send a mail using Django send_mail() but I can't get any mail from Django send_mail? Where is my mistake?

```
if request.method == "POST":
        depName = request.POST.get("sedep")
        Pname = request.POST.get("name")
        Pmail = request.POST.get("mail")
        docName = request.POST.get("sedoc")
        Pphone = request.POST.get("phone")
        AppointDate = request.POST.get("date")

        appointment_list = Appointment_List(se_dept = depName, se_doc = docName, patient_name = Pname, patient_phone = Pphone, patient_email = Pmail, calendar = AppointDate)
        appointment_list.save()

        # SEND EMAIL
        subject = 'Your appointment status!'
        message = 'hello '+ Pname + '! \n' + 'Welcome to Doctor appointment system.\n'+ 'Congratulations your appointment is booked.\n\n Thanking you Team malloc()'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [Pmail]
        send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently = True)
```

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sa3518548@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'uqnoifwqucnlefgp'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: might this article will help you how to setup it: https://agusmakmun.github.io/python/django/2016/04/18/email-backend-with-smtp-gmail.html

Comment: Did you see the error log? Pass the fail_silently False in the send_mail function. Also, check in gmail if it says there are any error.